# How to create identity column in SQL Server using with statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for some help in SQL, I am using following query

```
with t AS 
(
    select  
        EmpID, mgrid, HierarchyLevel, Description 
    from 
        empdatatest 
)
select * 
from t 
order by empid
```

I want a way so that table T has an identity column

Data output should be like

```
ID EmpID mgrid HierarchyLevel Description
------------------------------------------
1   201    7        1            Partner
2   202   201       2          Senior Manager
3   221   202       3           Manager
4   343   221       4           employee
5   534   221       4           employee
6   552   221       4           employee
```

Comment: Isn't EmpID already an identity column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;With t As 
(
    Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By EmpId) As ID,
            EmpID,
            mgrid,
            HierarchyLevel,
            Description
    From    empdatatest
)
Select  *
From    t
Order By empid;
```